# How do I update a value in mysql using jquery, php and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

HTML CODE:

```
<div class = "editprogramdetails" id = "editprogramblock" hidden = "true">
<?php
    $programid_query = @mysql_query("select id,program_name,company,date_prog from program_details");
    $row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($programid_query);
?>
ID: <input type = "textbox" id = "programnum" value = "<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" readonly/><br>
Program Name: <input type = "textbox" id = "prognameedit" placeholder = "<?php echo $row["program_name"] ?>" value = ""/><br>
Company Name: <input type = "textbox" id = "compnameedit" placeholder = "<?php echo $row["company"] ?>" value = ""/><br>
Date: <input type = "date" id = "dateedit" placeholder = "<?php echo $row["date_prog"] ?>" value = ""/><br>
<input type="button" class = "btn btn-default" id = "updatebutton" value ="Update"></input>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
 <script>

    $("#updatebutton").click(function(){
        var programidphp = $("#programnum").val();
        var programnamephp = $("#prognameedit").val();
        var companynamephp = $("#compnameedit").val();
        var datephp = $("#dateedit").val();

        var updaterequest = {
            upprogid = programidphp;
            upprognam = programnamephp;
            upcompnam = companynamephp;
            uppdate = datephp;
        };
        $.post("/TrainerApp/update_program.php", updaterequest).done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("Failed");
        });

    });
    </script>
```

update_program.php:

```
<?php


$username = "trainerapp";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";

$link = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
//echo $link;

if(@mysql_select_db("trainer_registration"))
{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection Error";
}

$upprogid = $_POST["upprogid"]
$upprognam = $_POST["upprognam"];
$upcompnam = $_POST["upcompnam"];
$uppdate = $_POST["uppdate"];

$upd_query = @mysql_query("UPDATE program_details SET program_name = '$upprognam', company = '$upcompnam', date_prog = '$uppdate' where id = '$upprogid'");

echo "Updated Successully";
?>
```

I am trying to update the values in the database. I don't know what mistake I am doing but I dont see any updates in the database. The username, password for the database is perfect because insertion works whereas update doesnt work. Please help.

Comment: What error you are getting? As i see in your update programe file you have written insertion code.

Comment: Where is your update query?

Comment: [You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
 Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: 'upcompanynam' does not exist in your POST. it's 'upcompnam'

Comment: Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. *Stop suppressing errors from your database interactions.*

Comment: you write insert query and asking for update why?

Comment: is this a typo `$row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($programid_query)` <= missing a semi-colon at the end

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information @VigneshAnandakumar

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm new to this.. I've made changes in the original post and I get no errors when I run this but still I dont see any update in the database..

Comment: `type = "textbox"` that's invalid. too many things wrong here.

Comment: Where are your form tags?

Comment: There were a few small corrections in the code, which I managed to solve by looking at console and also thank you for the comments.. I happened to check the code at the specific points where you guys spotted the mistake.. Thank you so much.. :)

Comment: so tell me; did you not see the answer I posted? silence isn't always golden you know. I hope I didn't do all this for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

***Nota:*** This is too long for comments.

Firstly, there is no `type = "textbox"` - `<input type = "textbox">`

- The syntax is `<input type = "text">`

So, change all of those to that format.

You are using `@` symbols often; those are error suppressors and won't help you during testing.

- I suggest you remove them (for now).

Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` to see if your query is failing.

- If all of those changes still don't work, you may have to add `<form></form>` tags with a POST method and check for errors.
- Since you're using jQuery, make sure you've loaded the library and using the right doctype for it.
- `UPDATE` is for existing data. If there is no data to update, then you may have wanted to use `INSERT INTO`. Only you know that.

About your Update button:

```
<input type="button" class = "btn btn-default" id = "updatebutton" value ="Update"></input>
```

You can safely remove `</input>` it isn't a valid closing tag.

or use `type="submit"` for it.

```
<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-default" id = "updatebutton" value ="Update">
```

However, you may want to use a button with a submit type for this,

Button with submit type:

```
<button type="submit" class = "btn btn-default" id = "updatebutton">Update</button>
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). 
[**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

> *"The username, password for the database is perfect because insertion works whereas update doesnt work."*

- You will need to make the comparison between those two different pieces of code in order to see what mistake you may have made.
- I believe you have enough to get you started.

---

**Final note(s):**

Try running your code without the jQuery/JS and adding a form with a POST method and an action to, i.e.: `<form action="/TrainerApp/update_program.php" method="post">...</form>`

If it works, then you may be having path problems with `$.post("/TrainerApp/update_program.php"`

and may need to use something like `$.post("../TrainerApp/update_program.php"`
or `$.post("/home/var/usr/public/TrainerApp/update_program.php"` as a full system path.